# Create JSON Object from Local JSON File

Tags: android, json, inputstream

How do I create a "JSONObject" from a local JSON file inside my "raw" folder.

I have the following JSON file under the "raw" folder of my android app project. The file is called "app_currencies.json". I need the information contained on this file as an **object** in my class. Below are the file contents:

```
{
  "EUR": { "currencyname":"Euro", "symbol":"EUR=X", "asset":"_European Union.png"},
  "HTG": { "currencyname":"Haitian Gourde", "symbol":"HTG=X", "asset":"ht.png"},
  "WST": { "currencyname":"Samoan Tala", "symbol":"WST=X", "asset":"ws.png"},
  "GBP": { "currencyname":"British Pound", "symbol":"GBP=X", "asset":"gb.png"}
}
```

I think what I need is to use the following:

```
//Get data from Json file and make it available through a JSONObject   
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.app_currencies.json);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject;
```

***jObject*** is what I need. I think I need an InputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream so that I can store it into JSONObject... the problem is that I'm not sure how to implement this code properly so that I can access the data? If any of you could give detailed instructions on how to do this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads a json file into a Json Array. See if it helps. Note, the file is stored in Assets instead

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        // open and read the file into a StringBuilder
        InputStream in =mContext.getAssets().open(mFilename);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // line breaks are omitted and irrelevant
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        // parse the JSON using JSONTokener
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString.toString()).nextValue();

        // do something here if needed from JSONObjects
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // we will ignore this one, since it happens when we start fresh
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
```